# xeditable select default value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a list of `titles` in my controller. And another list of `users`

My titles list contains all of the titles in my program and is collected from a database. The user object contains a single title property:

```
    $http.get(api.getUrl('user',null))
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response;
    });

$http.get(api.getUrl('title',null))
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.titles = response;
    });
```

As you can see from this example the `objects` in the `titles` does not have the same hashcode (and is therefore not the same `object`) as in my `user.title` object.

Now when my client clicks edit on a user i want the default value of my `xeditable` select to be equal to the title that the user currently have:

```
    <label class="font-bold block m-b-none" for="selected_title">Title</label>
<span class="block" id="selected_title" ng-model="selectedUser.title" editable-select="selectedUser.title" e-ng-options="title as title.name for title in titles">
    {{ selectedUser.title.name }}
</span>
```

However sadly the default value is `""` (nothing).

I feel like i have attempted everything can anyone point me in the right direction?

Please let me know if you need more information i will be watching the post alot.